# dataset.filter(col("a") !== col("b"));

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to filter the data present in a dataset based on the columns `a` and `b`. But, the statement,

```
dataset.filter(col("a") !== col("b")); //return 0
```

But there are some values for sure which satisfy this condition.

I tried with `=!=` and `.notEquals()` as well, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

change to **`!=`** - Will resolve the issue

e.g.

```
df = df.withColumn("cond_col", F.when(F.col("Primary_Email_Address") != F.col("Alternate_Email_Address"), True).otherwise(False))

+---------------------+-----------------------+--------+-----------------------------+
|Primary_Email_Address|Alternate_Email_Address|cond_col|merged_email                 |
+---------------------+-----------------------+--------+-----------------------------+
|navg@gmail.com       |navg@gmail.com         |false   |navg@gmail.com|navg@gmail.com|
|ggg@gmail.com        |nnnn@gmail.com         |true    |null                         |
+---------------------+-----------------------+--------+-----------------------------+
```